# What is promote to feature in qt creator and how does it work?

Tags: qt

I made an application for play audio video, but I cannot find QVideowidget from qt creator.

- How can I add this into the gui layout?
- Can promote to feature help?
- Is there any way to play a video in a qopengl widget?
- Any alternative of qvideo widgets so that I can drag and drop from qt creator?

Answer (score 9):

`Promote to` allows you replace (promote) a standard widget with a custom one. See the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) for details.

Instructions for `QVideoWidget`:

1. Add regular `QWidget` to the form.
2. Select `Promote to` from the added widget context menu.
3. In the dialog put `QVideoWidget` as `Promoted class name`, `Header file` should automatically become `qvideowidget.h`.
4. Click `Add`, and then `Promote`.
5. Now you have `QVideoWidget` on your form.