# Custom PyQt5 widgets Qt Designer

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have been trying (without success) to get Custom PyQt5 widgets to show up in Qt Designer for a couple of days now.

Some information: Window, Python 3.9.1, Pyqt5.15.6, Qt Designer 5.11.1

I have downloaded the source code for PyQt5-5.15.6 [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files), and I am trying to run the example under: `PyQt5-5.15.6\examples\designer\plugins`

Qt Designer does launch, but no additional widgets appear in the menu. Under `help > plugin information` it says: "Failed to extract plugin meta data from 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Qt Designer/plugins/designer/pyqt5.dll". Could this be why the widget imports are not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem:
I was using a standalone version of qt designer downloaded from [here](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download) which does not seem to support custom python widgets.

I eventually ended up using the qt designer installed by PySide6 (by installing PySide6 then running `pyside6-designer` from command line).
The custom widgets can then be added by creating a `widget_register.py` file for each custom widget using the [registerCustomWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtDesigner/QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection.html) method.

Be sure to then have the folder with the `widget_register.py` file(s) in your environment variables (`PYSIDE_DESIGNER_PLUGINS=C:\...\your_registrar_folder`) when starting Qt-Designer by either launching `PySide6-designer` from a script that first adds this variable to the environment each time or by manually adding the registrar folder to the system environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

> In Qt Designer there is a "Promote to..." feature to customize
> components. There you indicate the file and class respectively in
> "Header file" and "Promoted class name".

Here you see more information:

[What is promote to feature in qt creator and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588289/what-is-promote-to-feature-in-qt-creator-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: "Promote to..." unfortunately does not make it possible to edit (custom) widget properties in Qt Designer, only those present in the base-widget.

Comment: @Wouter that's not completely true: if you create a qt property for your custom widget, then you can set it using dynamic properties in Designer; just press the "+" button next to the filter of the property editor and add a property named as the one created for the custom class.