# PyQt6 QPlainTextEdit Mouse Click Event

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

How do you get the left mouse click event in a QPlainTextEdit?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.qpte = QPlainTextEdit("Click in this window")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qpte)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        print("mouseMoveEvent")

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print("mousePressEvent")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("mouseReleaseEvent")

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        print("mouseDoubleClickEvent")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

When you run the above code only the middle mouse and right mouse trigger the mousePressEvent.

Edit: I've also tried the following with the same result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.qpte = QPlainTextEdit("Click in this window")
        self.qpte.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qpte)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.qpte is obj:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                print('press')
                #self.pressed.emit(event.pos())
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseMove:
                print('move')
                #self.moved.emit(event.pos())
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
                print('release')
                #self.released.emit(event.pos())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

There must be a secret I've not discovered yet...

JT

Answer (score 0):

You've realized that mouse press events seem to go to the text edit, not the main window (because the text edit has the focus). Actually, [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractscrollarea.html#mousePressEvent) suggests that mouse-related events all go to the text edit's viewport() widget instead. Therefore, you can either install a filter event on the viewport() widget or subclass QPlainTextEdit to catch these event.

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent

class Edit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        print("mouseMoveEvent")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print("mousePressEvent")
        super().mousePressEvent(e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("mouseReleaseEvent")
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        print("mouseDoubleClickEvent")
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(e)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.qpte = Edit("Click in this window")
        # Mouse move events will only be catched when the mouse is pressed
        # unless setMouseTracking is set to True
        # self.qpte.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.qpte.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qpte)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.qpte.viewport():
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.FocusIn:
                print(event)
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                print('press')
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseMove:
                print('move')
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
                print('release')
            return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the working example. I set the central widget to the QPlainTextEdit because in my application the QPlainTextEdit is the only place I had that problem.

Comment: Is there a way to get the left mouse click without subclassing the QPlainTextEdit? The reason I ask is the QPlainTextEdit is part of a Qt Designer file that's imported into my app and if the correctly named QPlainTextEdit is found I add the function to it.

Comment: If you really don't want to subclass QPlainTextEdit, the only option I know is to install an event filter to the viewport() widget. You can also [promote a widget in a .ui file to your subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33590353/12682038).

Answer (score 0):

The object is to highlight a line that the user clicks in and the following code works as expected. However I don't understand what this line is doing and why it needs to create a new cursor to make it work.

```
cursor = QTextCursor(self.view.document().findBlockByNumber(selected_block))
```

The full working code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtGui import QTextCursor, QTextBlockFormat, QColor
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent, Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main window')
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.view = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        for i in range(25): # add some text to the text edit
            self.view.appendPlainText(f'Line: {i}')

        # move cursor to start of document
        self.cursor = self.view.textCursor()
        self.cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.MoveOperation.Start)
        self.view.setTextCursor(self.cursor)

        self.lbl = QLabel('Click on a line.')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.show()

    def show_line(self):
        # get a copy of the QTextCursor that represents the currently visible cursor
        cursor = self.view.textCursor()
        selected_block = cursor.blockNumber() # get current block number
        self.lbl.setText(f'Current line number: {selected_block}')
        format_normal = QTextBlockFormat()
        format_normal.setBackground(QColor('white'))
        highlight_format = QTextBlockFormat()
        highlight_format.setBackground(QColor('yellow'))
        cursor.select(QTextCursor.SelectionType.Document)
        cursor.setBlockFormat(format_normal) # clear the format
        # I'm not sure what's going on on the next line but it seems that is could be simpler
        cursor = QTextCursor(self.view.document().findBlockByNumber(selected_block))
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.MoveOperation.StartOfBlock, QTextCursor.MoveMode.MoveAnchor)
        cursor.setBlockFormat(highlight_format)
        self.view.setTextCursor(cursor)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.view.viewport() and event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
                self.show_line()
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: highlight selected line]

So if you left click on another line the hightlight moves to the new line.

JT

Comment: I wonder why stackoverflow changed the order of the posts?